# Can I infer a enum value, from a Generic param?

Tags: typescript

## What I want

I would like a general-use hook, to create getter/setters for a specific *Pre-existing* property. My **aspirational implementation** would look like:

```
const [getTitle, setTitle] = useUpdateState("title", "<defaultTitle>");
const [getAge, setAge] = useUpdateState("age", 44);
const [getErr, setErr] = useUpdateState("age", "44"); // Must error, as my types (defined elsewhere) state "age" must be number
```

Alternative:

```
const [getTitle, setTitle] = useUpdateState<TitleUpdate>("Mr");
const [getAge, setAge] = useUpdateState<AgeUpdate>(44);
const [getErr, setErr] = useUpdateState<AgeUpdate>("44"); // Must error
```

## What I have

But my **current implementation**  requires that I pass in a **type AND property**, to ensure the `defaultValue`'s type is correct.

```
const [getTitle, setTitle] = useUpdateState<TitleUpdate>(Properties.title, "Mr");
const [getAge, setAge] = useUpdateState<AgeUpdate>(Properties.age, 44);
const [getErr, setErr] = useUpdateState<AgeUpdate>(Properties.age, "44"); // Must Error!
```

It feels like both type and `property` should be unnecessary.

Here is the implementation I have so far ([TypeScriptPlaygroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=29&ssc=87&pln=29&pc=72#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewA7DgFwJbAM5QN4CwAUFKVJmgDbBQC8UA5BdQwDTFlQCGA5jfQ17A2xAL4BuYmgCeKKABUMVYAFUkAEy5p++KEkQp00gFywDqTDgB0zYKygA3LpTDBT2NHAwgeUCVNkaAEE+NU1tOl19ZAsTMxj0LGwrIXsnFzcocAgAI1Q-SSIAuTCtHUVlUoiAHygQ1Q0ywuJqNCgPMtNCEjIAbXgEy2TbAF1TCuoq4F6GdNcGEfYe0n7zROshMbrQxu0ZueFFsUjuzlXBpJslai2GEWWoc8MhlL4tgAYl0WJiAGMEEAeKBgbANcLAADKaDKkQAPCooMAAB7aEDqXBTAB8AApos84gNnkl7OpgAAzLhgShoABqzlcphU+3phwAlHRMfgOGQAPQ8qD-QFtPGxSKEixJXoAa2A0gQZKgKhG4igfKgsIAtFAAOpcEBtNAIKDeMn5NAACwwuDJiGgKm5pEFQL4aG0cEi2NZjOZGQWHPa0L2IqMyodAoBQNBrvy9GxB29sxZCy9jgQGHU-tOnDIHQi9DwUCsRdzdkLRYLvWDMi2Bz8fjD-geUbd2NJFKptJZrMKcGAaDAcBAjxdbvszdQoaI3yKRCdbV6LompajS5GkRBYLKULKsKXWOx4vWw2upYARABZOCn7t-CPzl31Md9+pr+gbqbb7Sw+r7w8vVJQAALIB3aqvy54gm0ACicCIHAACEt5CsOfYwXAT5oGhr7AqCH6BsA347OCOJ-pcAGnsB14qmqEFAmhCAIUAA))

```
enum Properties {
    title = 'title',
    age = 'age',
};
type TitleUpdate = { property: Properties.title, value: string };
type AgeUpdate = { property: Properties.age, value: number };

type Update = TitleUpdate | AgeUpdate;

let state: {
    [Properties.title]: TitleUpdate['value'],
    [Properties.age]: AgeUpdate['value'],
} = {
    [Properties.title]: '',
    [Properties.age]: 0,
}

const useUpdateState = <U extends Update>(property: Properties, defaultValue: U['value']) => {
    // const property = Properties[keyof U]; // <- Want to infer this from U
    const getter = (): U['value'] => state[property];
    const setter = (value: U['value']): void => {
        state = { ...state, ...{ [property]: value } }
    };
    setter(defaultValue);
return [getter, setter];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a bit easier to define a state shape, then restrict the hook to accept only valid state keys with corresponding valid values:

```
type State = { [Properties.title]: string, [Properties.age]: number };

const useUpdateState = <P extends keyof State>(property: P, defaultValue: State[P]) => {
// ...
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)